# Cannot edit FloatingActionButton image

Tags: android

I added a floatingActionButton on a layout file like following :

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/up_vid"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"

    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_up_vid"
    app:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

I expected my button shows the image on it but it only showed a black circle on its face. Is there anything I done wrong ?
The image is ic_up_vid.xml and imported as a vector asset from svg file.

Edit : Here is the xml file code.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="60dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    android:viewportWidth="60"
    android:viewportHeight="60">
<path
  android:pathData="M30,29.997m-29.996,0a29.996,29.996 0,1 1,59.992 0a29.996,29.996 0,1 1,-59.992 0"
  android:fillColor="#D4EDCF"/>
<path
  android:pathData="M36.75,11.724h12.25v1.651h-12.25z"
  android:fillColor="#FAFAFA"/>
<path
  android:pathData="M42.049,6.424h1.652v12.25h-1.652z"
  android:fillColor="#FAFAFA"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M30,29.999m-15.551,0a15.551,15.551 0,1 1,31.102 0a15.551,15.551 0,1 1,-31.102 0"
  android:strokeWidth="2"
  android:fillColor="#00000000"
  android:strokeColor="#69FF00"/>
<path
  android:pathData="M25.194,21.336l14.999,8.661l-15,8.659z"
  android:fillColor="#69FF00"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Use the `app:srcCompat` attribute

Comment: It does not work either. I edited the code to ''app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_up_vid"''

Comment: Which version of material components are you using?

Comment: Can you post your drawable code? I think that the problem is that you need to update its `android:fillColor` property. It happens with imported SVG.

Comment: @luca_999 I edited my question.

Comment: Try to add the `app:tint="@android:color/black"` property on the `FloatingActionButton` to see if there are any changes.

Comment: It seems that nothing happens

Comment: @MooNChilDSong did you run it on your device or emulator?

Comment: I run it on emulator